# ValueError: Spam or not Spam prediction using Linear Regression

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, linear-regression

I am trying to predict whether a message is Spam or Not. I have tokenized the texts and removed the stop words and punctuation to form a vector called "bag_of_Words".
Now I have been given task to apply linear regression and predict. How should I proceed as I am getting error when I fit the vector as input parameter.[data frame with vector as a column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng3j5.png).
Below is the code to do .fit()

```
clf = LinearRegression(normalize=True)
clf.fit(df3_tr['vect'],df3_te['type'])
```

Error is-: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
Please help me as I am unable to understand how to proceed further.

Comment: You need to convert your 'type' column into numeric values (1's and 0's), as the model will not understand text values.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question, but LogisticRegression is typically used when the outcome is binary, not LinearRegression.

Comment: Will the linear regression accept array as input parameter after I change type column into 1's and 0's.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) for .fit method, both predictor and target should be array-like objects.